# Why is MATCH against less effective than Exact match?

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I've a around 20 rows in MySQL table with the its `Title` column as `Elsewhere` and with other different column paramters.

I'm currently using a query like this, since most of my searches (via a PHP file) require me to give a close guess. So I use **FULLTEXT INDEX**

```
SELECT * FROM `my_db` WHERE MATCH (`Title`) AGAINST ('Elsewhere' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION) AND (Type ='movie' OR Type='series' OR Type IS NULL)
```

This works just fine, but sometimes, the most obviously of matches like this one gives me 0 rows. On the contrary, If I do something like :

```
SELECT * FROM `my_db` WHERE `Title` = "Elsewhere";
```

It gives me all the 20 rows.

Shouldn't the first case give more results compared to the last one for being less more specific?

**Note:** I'm using `MATCH` for a search. I do not want to perform an exact match everytime. Basically, a user input on the client side is being searched for on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `elsewhere` is a Stopword for MyISAM Full-text Search: Indexes http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html